# javascript open page in new tab and new links on that same tab

Tags: javascript

Basically I have a table where if the user clicks on id it opens a link on new tab. So if user clicks on another id it should open on that earlier tab and not make another new tab

```js
$scope.navigationUrl = function (event,item) {
 if (event.ctrlKey) {
  window.open('link' + item,"_blank"); // in new tab
    } else {
  $location.path('link' + item); // in same tab , yeah, this is completely wrong
    }
;
```

```html
<tbody>

<tr ng-repeat="case in LastBuild">
 <td colspan="1" ng-click="navigationUrl($event,case.id)">{{case.id}}</td>
 <td colspan="1">{{case.TimeTaken}}</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

The ctrl+click works as it opens the link on new tab everytime. But how can i keep the same tab for just click ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `window.open` method has parameters:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

If you define a name for a window, and use this on your javascript code, the named window will be replaced by the content.

Reference is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: That was pretty easy and I was trying stupid things.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "_Parent" instead of "_blank" for this.

```
if (event.ctrlKey) {
        window.open('link' + item,"_Parent"); // in new tab
}
```

Hope it will help.